# Check if json array exists c#

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a json object like so:

```
{
    "Name": "Mike",
    "Personaldetails": [
        {
            "Age": 25,
            "Surname": "Barnes"
        }
    ],
    "Address": [
        null
    ]
}
```

Now I have written C# to access this code and iterate over each object in the `"Personal Details"` array and into `"Address"` array.

How would I write a check to see if the array is null?

```
dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

foreach (var obj in jsonObject.Personaldetails)
{
     if (obj.Age = 24)
     {
          //do stuff
     }
}

//This is where I am stuck
if(jsonObject.Address = null)
{
    return "null array";
}
//If another json stream was not null at "Address" array
else
{
    foreach (var obj in jsonObject.Address)
    {
         if (obj.arrayItem == "Something")
         {
              //do stuff
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use == instead of = for comparisons in the if statements

Comment: What you've posted is not valid JSON (specifically the `Personaldetails` property's value).

Comment: happy now @Jonesy and @Andrew?

Comment: We're trying to help, take it easy.  Also your code doesn't reflect those changes

Comment: Thanks for the updates--this still won't run for me though. I get a runtime error that `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` does not contain a definition for Personaldetails. Are you using JSON.NET?

Comment: indeed I am using JSON.NET

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right as no one else seems to be paying attention, here is the answer...

The problem is with this bit of code:

```
"Address": [
    null
]
```

You are trying to check if `Address` is null, however this JSON does not represent a `null` `Address`. It shows a valid array, with one single `null` object. If this is correct, then you may want to try this:

```
if(jsonObject.Address == null || (jsonObject.Address[0] == null))
{
    return "null array";
}
```

Firstly, notice the use of `==` to check equality (rather than `=` for assignment).

Secondly, this will check if `Address` is null OR if the first object of the array is `null`, which I assume is what you are trying to do. It may also be worth adding in a length check to see if the array is just a single null element - but that depends on your requirements

Comment: Wow @musefan you're really good a reiterating previously posted answers.

Comment: @RobCarroll: Wrong, your answer mentioned nothing about checking the first item in the array at the time I started to write my answer. When I started writing, your answer only made comment about the `=` > `==` solution, which is only part of the problem

Comment: @RobCarroll First, the operator should be `||` not `&&`. Second your `Count()` will throw exception. I guess you posted it without checking....

Answer (score 1):

Your missing the double "==" to check for comparison, "=" is an assignment operation.

```
if(jsonObject.Address == null)
{
    return "null array";
}
```

Your JSON should look like this. Otherwise your not checking for a null array but instead an array with a null value for the first element of the array.

```
{
    "Name": "Mike",
    "Personaldetails": [
        {
            "Age": 25,
            "Surname": "Barnes"
        }
    ],
    "Address":  null
}
```

Then the code would be the following:

```
if(jsonObject.Address == null)
{
    return "null array";
}
```

If you need to keep the original JSON you can always do a check like so:

```
if(jsonObject.Address.Length > 0 && jsonObject.Address[0] == null)
{
    return "null array";
}
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is the array is not null. It is an array that contains a single null value

Comment: Your JSON is not valid then, use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ or http://www.jsonmate.com to validate your JSON. Is this JSON that you have created or JSON that is being passed to you?

Comment: No I did not get this passed to me @musefan, I quickly created it and forgot to use `{}` for items within a Json array. So please guys its just a simple mistake which I have corrected and validated.

Comment: If you look at the time of my question edit you will see that I have corrected the json sample.

Comment: `.count()` ?? **a)** starts with lowercase **b)** Linq with *dynamic* ?